# Homebrew PHP 7.1 (macOS Sierra) Apache Syntax Error

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, php-7.1

So I've been following along with [This Tutorial](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions), which helps configure Apache 2.4 with multiple versions of PHP. Everything was going quite smoothly, and all of my PHP versions worked, except for 7.1. When attempting to start the Apache server to receive the phpinfo of 7.1, I received the following error message:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 178 of 
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: 
dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found
```

This is the code that exists on line 178:

```
LoadModule php7_module  /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

I tried running

```
brew reinstall php71 --with-httpd24
```

and restarted the Apache server. Still receiving the same error message. Any idea what went wrong? I appreciate any responses! Many thanks!

Comment: Did you verify that the `/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` file exists now?

Comment: Recently Homebrew has changed the naming scheme of the PHP versions (following the general naming scheme they introduced last year for older versions of programs). Use `brew --prefix php71` (or `php@7.1` if `php71` doesn't work) to find out where to search for `libphp7.so`.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem.

For me, homebrew has a different folder structure in `/usr/local/opt` where folders are more like `/usr/local/opt/php@7.1`

So I needed to find where `libphp7.so` lived, or if it existed at all.

Running `find /usr -name "libphp7.so"`

Came back with:

`/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` and 
`/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.15/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

Both work in place of `/usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` for me and I'll update if required in the future.

So I updated `httpd.conf` to use

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.15/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

Then I restarted apache with `sudo apachectl -k restart` and all is well.

Comment: Also run the command brew info php. Under the caveat section, check out for the LoadModule location and paste it in httpd.conf

Comment: Why `brew link php@7.x` does't also make that changes? We can still see that `/usr/local/opt/php` still goes to `../Cellar/8.1.4` (previously I set my PHP to 8.1.4)

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting this error with the brew install php. then 
apachectl -t to test syntax

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 180 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib\n in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

For some reason??? I found the libphp7.so here

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Plugged it in and it works.
However - I'm no clearer as to why the first one is failing.

Comment: The php you activated is the default PHP version that ships with the OS, in case of Mojave it is 7.1.33

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew instructed to add this to my httpd.conf file:

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

I tried stopping and restarting only to get the same error. After updating several times with different options, this one finally worked for me.

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Answer (score 1):

I had a PHP update, the file path has been changed. I changed the module path in `httpd.conf`.

Before:

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

After:

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.12/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with php 7.2.

Running `brew linkage php` showed that there were some broken dependencies.

So running `brew update && brew upgrade` resolved it for me.

Comment: This worked for me when Big Sur 11.3 update nerfed a lot of my M1 Mac.

Answer (score 0):

in usr/local/opt there was an folder(alias) php only

```
`Just duplicate the php Alias-Folder and rename it to php@7.4`
```

after that
sudo apache graceful
I was done

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the path of php7.4 on httpd.conf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

This was the solution for me:

*My chip is Apple M1, running macOS Big Sur version 11.4.*

I had to change this line (the module path) in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

to this:

```
LoadModule php7_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```